# query string parameter breaks into characters issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, http

I am passing a query string to my get url. In my application, i am following this kind of syntax to fetch the data. I am getting 404 error. While checking the query parameter, that query string splited into characters.

```
loadLayoutData() {
  const dataParams = { this.passedData };
   http
    .request(this.PageId, 'DataServiceId', {
      query: dataParams
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.layoutData = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

Query String is(this.passedData) : "DOG" . It is showing in query string parameters like this -> 0:D 1:O 2:G .

I want the query string as a string format not breaking into characters.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a syntax error with `const dataParams = { this.passedData };`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are now showing how passedData is buiding, I'll only focus on answering how you can deal with this splitted string.

In this case, if I understood well, if you have something like ['D', 'O', 'G'], you can use:

```
query = ['D', 'O', 'G'].join('');
```

doing this, it'll return "DOG". Please let me know if it answered your question